# If statements and methods

Tags: c#

first time posting and have a question about if statements with methods.

I have been trying multiple ways of doing this and haven't gotten it to work. I am trying to call methods based on if the user types a number between 1 and 6. This is what I got so far, please don't judge the dialogue of the calculator (I'm only 14).

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(Work());
    }

    public static void Work(int input)
    {
        if (input < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 1 and 6");
        }
        else if (input == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Add());
        }
        else if (input == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Subtract());
        }



    }

    public static int Add()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hey bro, need a new number man!");
        string input1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Gnarly dude, how 'bout a second one?");
        string input2 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Here botine-shake, there is your final number.");

        int num1 = int.Parse(input1);
        int num2 = int.Parse(input2);

        int result = num1 + num2;
        return result;
    }

    public static int Subtract()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number. Now. Please hurry.");
        string input1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Need another number. Hurry.");
        string input2 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Here is your number. Now please leave.");

        int num1 = int.Parse(input1);
        int num2 = int.Parse(input2);

        int result = num1 - num2;
        return result;
    }

    public static int Multiply()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Gimme that number.");
        string input1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Ok, how would you like to give me another?");
        string input2 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Here you go baby.");

        int num1 = int.Parse(input1);
        int num2 = int.Parse(input2);

        int result = num1 * num2;
        return result;
    }

    public static decimal Divide()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("/enter.Num1");
        string input1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("/enter.Num2");
        string input2 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("/final.Dividend");

        decimal num1 = decimal.Parse(input1);
        decimal num2 = decimal.Parse(input2);

        decimal result = num1 / num2;
        return result;
    }

    public static int Square()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What number do you want SQUARED?");
        string input1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Here's your square!");


        int num1 = int.Parse(input1);
        int result = num1 * num1;
            return result;
    }

    public static int Cube()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What have thine want CUBED?");
        string input1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Here, I bestow upon you your cube...");

        int num1 = int.Parse(input1);
        int result = num1 * num1 * num1;
        return result;
    }





}
```

Comment: ok, so I'm assuming that your trying to call the work(), and your if conditions seem correct, you would need to write out ALL the if conditions from 1-6 in the work() method, an alternative would be to use switch case statement, but not recommended. I need more context to solve the issue.

Comment: @Suthanth M, thank you for your help and time. I'll try that, seems that may be the issue.

Comment: You never provide a number to the Work constructor so input will equal null meaning no function is chosen and called. What happens if you put (just to test) `Console.WriteLine(Work(1));` ?

Comment: You are trying to execute a function based on the user input, but you never capture the user input that should help you to decide which function to execute. 

@Liam's answer should help you to achieve what you need but since you are new to programming i would like to give you a more general advice. Try to use [Pseudocode](https://kopywritingkourse.com/guides/how-to-write-pseudocode/) to define the logic and flow of your application before trying to implement it. That should help you to divide your logic in small and more manageable pieces.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand what you mean, but there should be something needs to be fixed:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Work());
}
public static void Work(int input)
......
```

You can see the `Work()` is an "Action", not a "Function". Because it returns nothing, so it's not appropriate to `WriteLine` the result from `Work()`

By the way, you can see the `Work(int input)` needs an input, which obviously you didn't provide.
Try This:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int myInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Work(myInput);
}
public static void Work(int input)
{ .....
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code that you provided it looks like you're not asking for user input before calling your Work method, so nothing will happen since there is no argument being passed to the Work method.

You should try something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    CaptureUserInput();
}

public static void WriteInstructions() {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 1 and 6 to perform a calculation");
    // instruct the user for each available operation
    Console.WriteLine("1: Addition");
    Console.WriteLine("2: Subtraction");
}

public static void CaptureUserInput() {
    WriteInstructions();

    // capture the user's input and convert it to an integer
    string stringInput = Console.Readline();
    int input = int.Parse(stringInput);

    // validate that it is a valid integer
    if (Enumerable.Range(1,6).Contains(input)) {
        // this is a valid number in the range we want, call the Work method
        Work(input);
    } else {
        // the user has entered an invalid entry, prompt them and wait for another attempt
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, that is an invalid option.");
        CaptureUserInput();
    }
}
```

Note that this is setup so that you can recursively handle when a user enters something that that's not a number or outside the range from 1 - 6. This will prompt the user they entered something invalid and then wait for the next attempt to enter a number.